# Change EUID of running process

Tags: linux, security, process, permissions

On Linux how can I change EUID of running process from command line (provided I have root access)?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can, I am not aware of any syscall that lets you change the effective user id of any process but the calling process.

Answer (score 0):

There's [kchuid](http://www.nimh.org/code/kchuid/), but that requires you to compile your own kernel modules, was last updated in 2002, and looks extremely feary.

Alternatively, you could do probably do some ptrace hacks, but a sample or direction is bit beyond me.

Answer (score 0):

Use gdb.

`# gdb -p pid`

`(gdb) p seteuid(userid)`

Comment: This requires that _pid_ is running as root already - calls run via `p` run in the context of the traced process.